# how to user following error style in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

[image]

I want to use following style like lighting style in visualforce page but how can I realize it ? I have searched in google but can not find a good solution. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply embed a lightning component into the visualforce page to save yourself the hassle.

- [Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)

You can alson style your visualforce page with SLDS

- [Automatic Lightning Styles for Visualforce](http://peterknolle.com/automatic-lightning-styles-for-visualforce/)
- [Use the Salesforce Lightning Design System to Style Visualforce Pages](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/workshop-lightning-design-system-visualforce)
- [Lightning Design System](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_design_system)

and add client-side logic to reproduce the exact behavior on required fields.